# If a thief comes by day may one kill him in self defence

Tags: gezel-stealing, murder, daytime, maseches-pesachim

The gemoro psochim 2b mentions only about a 'ganev' (stealthy thief) coming at night that one may kill the thief even if he is not sure this thief is about to kill him. What about if this thief came by day? Is he allowed to kill the thief even if he is not sure this 'ganev' would kill him if he doesn't get his money otherwise.

Comment: I seem to recall learning that the day/night distinction is what's important here; the nighttime ganav knows this is a possible outcome, but the daytime one doesn't expect to find someone at home.  So I would *expect* the day case to be governed by the same halacha as other threats to life/health.

Comment: You remember correctly. Raavad g'naiva 9:8. Since the simple wording of the posuk says if the sun arises he may not kill him. But see 'even hozel' that others argue.

Answer (score -1):

if somoene breaks into your house they are a threat to your safety and you may kill them. unless... they cower and show physically by submitting such as lying on the ground with their hands on their head or if they run away. If the thief submits or suns away they are no longer a threat and killing them would not be self defense anymore.

Comment: Did you learn this somewhere, or is it just your own opinion?